# ActionScript 2.0 Import package into Timeline script

Tags: actionscript-2, flash-cs4

All,
I have been trying to import some sample actionscript package into my flash project.
The sample code is defined in the org.red5.flash.bwcheck package.

In my flash project's (flash 8 and actionscript 2.0) actions frame:

I added these lines at the beginning:

```
import org.red5.flash.bwcheck.app.*;
import org.red5.flash.bwcheck.events.*;
import org.red5.flash.bwcheck.*;
```

and add the call to this package in my code

```
function start()
{
    serverURL = settingsManager.getIP();
    serverApplication = "live";
    clientServerService = "checkBandwidthUp";
    serverClientService = "checkBandwidth";
    trace("calling connect()");
    connect();
}
```

The connect() is a function defined org.red5.flash.bwcheck.app.BandwidthDetectionApp. 
Nothing happens when I test the movie.

I added these paths to both action script 2.0's settings and project preferences:
./org/red5/flash/bwcheck
./org/red5/flash/bwcheck/app
./org/red5/flash/bwcheck/events

when I test or debug movie, the connect() does not seem to be called.

If I called the connect with the full path name:

Then I got a lot of syntax errors about the sample code which should not have errors.

My question is how do I import package and use it in my Actions Frame?

Thanks,
Peter